# Obtener valor determinado de una imagen

Tags: android

Estoy planteando una aplicación para Android para la gestión de gastos y se me ha planteado la siguiente duda ¿Es posible obtener un valor numérico determinado de una imagen? por ejemplo, el total de la factura de la luz.

Saludos.

Comment: tu vas a definir el tipo de gráfico del cual obtener el valor o este ya fue definido por alguien?

Comment: Lo que te planteas podría llamarse [OCR o ROC](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconocimiento_%C3%B3ptico_de_caracteres) quizas te ayude !

Comment: Efectivamente, me ha ayudado bastante porque que no sabía por donde empezar a buscar al no saber si era o no posible. Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Necesitarias hacer reconocimiento de imagenes, Google tiene una API que te podria a hacerlo, puedes ver la documentación en el siguiente link [CLOUD VISION API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2016-q1-cloud-latam-ML-skws-freetrial), espero que te ayude.

Comment: Ya la estoy viendo, es una pasada. Muchas Gracias.